# Is there a Java technique to solve duplicate loops in a class?

Tags: java, algorithm, refactoring

I recently submitted this code as part of a coding challenge online, as part of my feedback I was told that parts of my code could be improved to fit "good practice". I have tried to reduce the amount of lines however I wasn't given any tips, I am still unsure how to improve. I hope I can get some assistance.

```
public class ArrayChecker {
  public boolean check(int[] expected, int[] actual, int maxValue, int delta) {
    // Clip 'too large' values
    for (int i = 0; i < actual.length; ++i) {
      if (actual[i] > maxValue) {
        actual[i] = maxValue;
      }
    }

    // Check for length differences
    if (actual.length != expected.length) {
      return false;
    }

    // Check that each entry is within the expected +/- delta
    for (int i = 0; i < actual.length; ++i) {
      if (Math.abs(expected[i] - actual[i]) > delta) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you think the duplicate loops are? they each do something different

Comment: Also, you can preform both logics in the same loop as they're not dependent on each other.

Comment: Put the length difference check first. Then just combine the two loop bodies. (Except don't actually update the array elements, just store the clipped value in a variable).

Comment: I would put length check first - as there is no point to do any loops.
loops can be merged into one single

Comment: For starters your method name could be more descriptive, i'm assuming the contents of actual should match those in expected, not exceeding the max value and within the defined delta. You're iterating over the array twice, you only need to do that once, also you should perform the length check first, since if they are different you will waste time iterating over the previous array. Also you should be using `i++` in your loops.

Comment: I recommend you check out [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first check the lengths of `actual` and `expected`. Then, I would test the delta and perform the clipping in one loop and with one step (`Math.min(int, int)` can help). Like,

```
public boolean check(int[] expected, int[] actual, int maxValue, int delta) {
    if (actual.length != expected.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < actual.length; ++i) {
        if (Math.abs(expected[i] - Math.min(maxValue, actual[i])) > delta) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If using Java 8+ you can reduce that to a lambda.

```
public boolean check(int[] expected, int[] actual, int maxValue, int delta) {
    if (actual.length != expected.length) {
        return false;
    }
    return IntStream.range(0, actual.length)
            .noneMatch(i -> Math.abs(expected[i] - Math.min(maxValue, actual[i])) > delta);
 }
```

And finally, a (complex) one line return, like

```
public boolean check(int[] expected, int[] actual, int maxValue, int delta) {
    return actual.length == expected.length && IntStream.range(0, actual.length)
            .noneMatch(i -> Math.abs(expected[i] - Math.min(maxValue, actual[i])) > delta);
}
```